# class Bar { operator Foo(); }

Tags: c++, constructor, operator-overloading

What does this style of operator overloading mean?

```
class Foo {
    Foo(int a) { ... }
};

class Bar {
    operator Foo() { return Foo(25); }
};
```

Answer (score 11):

That is user-defined conversion function which converts an instance of `Bar` into `Foo` implicitly.

```
Bar bar;

Foo foo = bar;  // bar implicitly converts into Foo.
```

It is as if you've written this:

```
Foo foo = Foo(25);
```

If you've such a conversion function, then you can call this:

```
void f(Foo foo); //a function which accepts Foo

f(bar); // bar implicitly converts into Foo.
```

So such *implicit* conversion may not be desirable sometime, as it might cause problem, producing unintended result. To avoid that, you can make the conversion function *explicit* as (in C++11 only):

```
//valid in C++11 only

class Bar {
  explicit  operator Foo() { return Foo(25); }
};
```

Now both of these would give error:

```
Foo foo = bar; //error
f(bar); //error
```

However, the following is allowed:

```
Foo foo = static_cast<Foo>(bar); //Ok
f(static_cast<Foo>(bar)); //Ok
```

Comment: Using `explicit` for operator conversion is introduced in C++11? AFAIR only constructors could be explicit in c++03 or perhaps I dont remember correctly...

Comment: @Als: You're right. In C++03, only constructors can be explicit. I made this clear in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's an overload of the `cast operator`.  Best documentation I could find was [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts48df3y%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Basically, if you have a `Bar` you can cast it to a `Foo` which is constructed with a specific value:

```
Bar b;
Foo f = b;
```